# How Oracle GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS works

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have one of our system that perform quite a bit of database activity in terms of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements against various tables. Because of this the statistics became stale and this is reflected in overall performance.

We want to create a scheduled job that would periodically invoke `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`. Because we don't want actual stats gathering itself to impact the system processing even more we are thinking to collect statistics quite frequent and use `GATHER STALE` option:

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(OWNNAME => 'MY_SCHEMA', OPTIONS =>'GATHER STALE')
```

This executes almost instantly but running this statement below **before** and **after** stats gathering seems to bring back the same records with the same values:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tab_modifications WHERE inserts + updates + deletes > 0;
```

The very short time taking to execute and the fact that user_tab_modifications content stays the same makes me question if `OPTIONS =>'GATHER STALE'` actually does what we expect it should do. On the other hand if I run this again **before** and **after** statistics gathering I can see the tables reported as stale before re no longer reported as stale after:

```
DECLARE
   stale dbms_stats.objecttab;
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(ownname => 'MY_SCHEMA', OPTIONS =>'LIST STALE', objlist => stale);
  FOR i in 1 .. stale.count 
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( stale(i).objName );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

On another hand if lets say `my_table` is one of my tables being listed as part of the tables that part of the `user_tab_modifications` with `inserts + updates + deletes  > 0` and I run I can see `my_table` no longer being reported as having changes.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => 'MY_SCHEMA', tabname => 'MY_TABLE');
```

So my questions are:

1. Is my approach correct. Can I trust I am getting fresh stats just by running `options => 'GATHER STALE'` or I should manually collect stats for all tables that come back with a reasonable number of inserts, updates, deletes?
2. When user_tab_modifications would actually get reset; obviously `GATHER STALE` option does not seem to do it

We are using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Not sure why my question is flagged about not being about programming. DBMS_STATS is an oracle package and I want to know what is the best way to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following info from Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5480.htm#REFRN26280).

You should enable monitoring if you use GATHER_DATABASE_STATS or GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS with the GATHER AUTO or GATHER STALE options.

This view USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS is populated only for tables with the MONITORING attribute. It is intended for statistics collection over a long period of time. For performance reasons, the Oracle Database does not populate this view immediately when the actual modifications occur. Run the FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO procedure in the DBMS_STATS PL/SQL package to populate this view with the latest information. The ANALYZE_ANY system privilege is required to run this procedure.

Hope this helps you to identify which of your assumptions are incorrect and understand the correct usage of "GATHER STALE".